# Absolutely positioned span inside h3 won't break to next line when outside div boundaries

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a `span` that is inside of an `h3` which is inside of a `div`. The `div` has a set width to it. The rest of the text of the h3 will break to the next line, except the span text, since it has `position:absolute` on it.

The example code is as follows:

```css
    html{
      background:gray;
    }
    div{
      width:200px;
      background:black;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    h3{
      color:white;
    }
    span{
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 8px;
      height: 28px;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <h3> This needs to break  
        <span> but it doesn't...</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
```

And you can see [a working example here](http://codepen.io/maudulus/pen/pjbYRM).

Comment: absolute positioned elements will not effect the flow of document. And it will not break. if you want to break it why did you make it absolute? what's the case?

Comment: It can break but probably not how you would expect - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gaMEQZ

Comment: Feels like an [**XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @AsimKT I have to have spans that roll in and out. I'll adjust the code on the codepen so you can see.

Comment: @AsimKT I adjusted the code so that you can see why I'm doing that.

Comment: I was trying to do something like http://codepen.io/maudulus/pen/RWRMwj but the breaking on the code/ skipping/ jerkiness made me reconsider.

Comment: I think I didn't clearly understood you. http://codepen.io/asimkt/pen/meRyqz. Is this helpful?

Comment: Thanks @AsimKT for the help!